# I want to unchecked radio button on the form and other form

Tags: vb.net

i make a method to clear all text box and label in all form by call the method but i dont know how to unchecked radio button by using this controls

```
        For Each myCtrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
            If TypeOf myCtrl Is TextBox Then
                myCtrl.Text = ""
            End If
            If TypeOf myCtrl Is Label Then
                myCtrl.Text = ""
            End If
            If TypeOf myCtrl Is RadioButton Then

            End If
            If myCtrl.HasChildren Then Txtclear(myCtrl)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `RadioButton.Checked = False` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because all controls implement the `Text` property, you only need to test for controls that have other properties you want to change and then in-line cast to that type to expose the specific property:

```
For Each myCtrl As Control In ctrl.Controls
    Select Case True
        ' This test isn't required, just use the `Else` below
        Case TypeOf myCtrl Is TextBox, TypeOf myCtrl Is Label
            myCtrl.Text = ""
        Case TypeOf myCtrl Is RadioButton
            CType(myCtrl, RadioButton).Checked = False
        Case Else
            myCtrl.Text = ""
   End Select
Next myCtrl
```